# Are questions on preferring a db type, brand for some app tasks on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Is it appropriate to ask questions on:

**what database types and specifically which vendors (brands) of databases should be preferred for use in some specific use cases occur in web applications that require databases?**

Use cases are like;

- storing user credentials that users use to login
- storing timelines, newsfeed in other words, posts of users.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It would be very rare for this sort of question to be accepted by the community here.

The potential problems are many, but include:

- Answers tend to go out of date more quickly than for other types of question
- Answers are often based on personal preferences
- The questions are too often lacking enough detail, resulting in extended discussion
- These types of questions tend to attract spam answers

This type of question may be on-topic for [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Be sure to take the [tour](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour), and read their [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) before posting though.

Note I'm not saying that an exceptional question of this sort could never be on-topic, well-received, and fully answered here, just that it is relatively unlikely, and not our [experience to date](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes%20which%20database).

---

Update: the [question was asked](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/124894/1192) and closed by the community (and now deleted).

Comment: Basically, just imagine reading a question of this kind posted 10 or 15 years ago – how useful would you find it today?

Comment: I understand the "Answers tend to go out of date more quickly than for other types of question" argument. But  I think it is right to an extent regarding **first**, there are some other types of questions even a simple programming question with code snippets on an algorithm may go out of date, and **second**, this approach leaves no option for that kind of questions, leaves them not unanswered but even unquestioned :), while permitting **first** kind, which it actually must permit in order such networks could go on living.

Comment: So maybe those 10 or 15 yeas of time span should not be required to be vailid. Today we start to use ES6 and ES7, some Javascript questions of near past are already and inevitably invalid, that is not a big problem, some questions are inevitably are localised in time and answers to them are needed in that time. Answering that need is not necessarily being unorganised, or being low quality.

Comment: So, @ışık - ask your question, and let's see where it goes.